# OpenVPN GUI loaded on start up on Windows 10 but is missing in the system tray

Tags: windows-10, openvpn

OpenVPN GUI is loaded on start up but the GUI icon is nowhere to be found. It has been configured to startup and connect automatically but it does not even connect.

I want to have it automatically start with Windows startup without having to manually connect and/or end or restart processes.

Comment: How did you set it to start up...try follow these instructions: https://www.cactusvpn.com/tutorials/how-to-auto-start-openvpn-gui-on-windows/

Comment: I don't know where the GUI was loaded from or how to get the icon but I did manage to stop that from happening (I think I deleted the icon in the StartUp folder. I found two: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp and C:\Users\awesome-user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup)

I then tried the instructions you provided and it works perfectly. Thanks for sharing it!

Comment: I have same problem / windows 10 professional / openvpn-gui from openvpn  web site. I can see it's running but system tray is missing. It's even says that "Already running ... click system tray"

Comment: @ClariceBouwer It's likely one of the OpenVPN services were starting at log in, but the GUI executable was not... this would cause OpenVPN to show as running, but not display it's GUI control panel within the Task Bar.  As to the two locations, `%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` contains the Start Menu entries for all users, whereas `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu` contains user-specific Start Menu entries that will only show up in the Start Meu when that user is logged in _(OpenVPN's GUI is generally placed in the latter's `Startup` folder)_.

Answer (score 1):

I killed OpenVPN-gui.exe using task manager.  It happened so that It has a new icon like this  [image]. I also went to settings to tell Windows 10 to show this icon always in the taskbar (not behind arrow mark)

I had to do it multiple times.